# Using rgl with headless display

Tags: r, shell, xvfb, rgl

I installed Xfvb and instantiated a display instance:

```
$ Xvfb :2 -screen 0 1280x960x24 &
```

I then installed R 3.2.5 and rgl 0.95.1441 separately from source, and I opened R with a connection to `DISPLAY` on port 2. I then tried to run a test rgl session with some basic rgl routines:

```
$ DISPLAY=:2 /usr/local/bin/R
R version 3.2.5 (2016-04-14) -- "Very, Very Secure Dishes"
...
> library(rgl)
> open3d()
> x <- sort(rnorm(1000))
> y <- rnorm(1000)
> z <- rnorm(1000) + atan2(x,y)
glX
 1
> plot3d(x, y, z, col=rainbow(1000))
> rgl.postscript("foo.pdf", fmt="pdf")
> sessionInfo()
```

The `rgl.postscript()` command here should print out a PDF file containing the rendering of the data points passed to `plot3d()`. However, the resulting PDF file is blank.

Is there a configuration issue with how I installed or instantiated Xvfb and/or R, which is causing display problems?

---

Here is a log of a typical run session:

```
R version 3.2.5 (2016-04-14)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Fedora release 14 (Laughlin)

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C
 [3] LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8
 [7] LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  base

other attached packages:
[1] rgl_0.95.1441  optparse_1.3.2

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] getopt_1.20.0 methods_3.2.5

5 XSELINUXs still allocated at reset
SCREEN: 0 objects of 136 bytes = 0 total bytes 0 private allocs
DEVICE: 4 objects of 32 bytes = 128 total bytes 0 private allocs
CLIENT: 0 objects of 160 bytes = 0 total bytes 0 private allocs
WINDOW: 0 objects of 48 bytes = 0 total bytes 0 private allocs
PIXMAP: 1 objects of 16 bytes = 16 total bytes 0 private allocs
GC: 0 objects of 56 bytes = 0 total bytes 0 private allocs
CURSOR: 0 objects of 8 bytes = 0 total bytes 0 private allocs
CURSOR_BITS: 0 objects of 8 bytes = 0 total bytes 0 private allocs
DBE_WINDOW: 0 objects of 24 bytes = 0 total bytes 0 private allocs
TOTAL: 5 objects, 144 bytes, 0 allocs
4 DEVICEs still allocated at reset
DEVICE: 4 objects of 32 bytes = 128 total bytes 0 private allocs
CLIENT: 0 objects of 160 bytes = 0 total bytes 0 private allocs
WINDOW: 0 objects of 48 bytes = 0 total bytes 0 private allocs
PIXMAP: 1 objects of 16 bytes = 16 total bytes 0 private allocs
GC: 0 objects of 56 bytes = 0 total bytes 0 private allocs
CURSOR: 0 objects of 8 bytes = 0 total bytes 0 private allocs
CURSOR_BITS: 0 objects of 8 bytes = 0 total bytes 0 private allocs
DBE_WINDOW: 0 objects of 24 bytes = 0 total bytes 0 private allocs
TOTAL: 5 objects, 144 bytes, 0 allocs
1 PIXMAPs still allocated at reset
PIXMAP: 1 objects of 16 bytes = 16 total bytes 0 private allocs
GC: 0 objects of 56 bytes = 0 total bytes 0 private allocs
CURSOR: 0 objects of 8 bytes = 0 total bytes 0 private allocs
CURSOR_BITS: 0 objects of 8 bytes = 0 total bytes 0 private allocs
DBE_WINDOW: 0 objects of 24 bytes = 0 total bytes 0 private allocs
TOTAL: 1 objects, 16 bytes, 0 allocs
```

In addition to Fedora 14, I have also tested the same version of `R` and `rgl` under CentOS Linux release 7.2.1511.

On the Fedora 14 box, I am running:

```
xorg-x11-server-Xvfb.x86_64   v1.9.5-2.fc14
```

On the CentOS 7 box, I am running:

```
xorg-x11-server-Xvfb.x86_64   v1.17.2-10.el7
```

Under both test servers, when I run my test `R` script, I get a white, empty PDF from `rgl.postscript()` and black, empty PNG from `rgl.snapshot()` (along with the same `Xvfb` log statements).

I should stress that I am looking to create a PDF file containing the rendered scene, which is in a vector-based format. While `rgl.snapshot()` may help with troubleshooting the cause of the problem, that call returns a PNG bitmap, not a vector-formatted PDF. A bitmap is not useful as a final product for my purposes.

In addition to running `R` with the `DISPLAY` variable setting passed to it, I also have used `export`:

```
$ DISPLAY=:2 /usr/local/bin/R
```

Or:

```
$ export DISPLAY=":2" 
$ /usr/local/bin/R
...
```

Either approach yields the same results.

If other details would be of use, please feel free to leave a comment with specifics and I'll do what I can to follow up.

---

Neither the Fedora 14 nor the CentOS 7 box should have proprietary libgl drivers. To the best of my knowledge, these are standalone, headless servers. The Fedora 14 box is actually a virtual machine. If there is a specific way to confirm, please let me know.

I have the following `Xdummy` package installed under the Fedora 14 headless server:

```
xorg-x11-drv-dummy.x86_64   v0.3.4-1.fc14
```

On the CentOS 7 machine:

```
xorg-x11-drv-dummy.x86_64   v0.3.6-21.el7
```

On the CentOS 7 server, I run the [Xdummy](http://www.karlrunge.com/x11vnc/Xdummy) script to create a display on `:10`:

```
$ sudo ./Xdummy -debug :10 -depth 16 -geom 1024x768
```

In another shell, I run R and the test rgl routines:

```
$ DISPLAY=":10" /usr/local/bin/R
...
> library(rgl)
> open3d()
> x <- sort(rnorm(1000))
> y <- rnorm(1000)
> z <- rnorm(1000) + atan2(x,y)
> plot3d(x, y, z, col=rainbow(1000))
> rgl.postscript("foo.pdf", fmt="pdf")
```

As with `Xvfb`, the resulting PDF file is a blank document and contains no data points.

Comment: I haven't used Xvfb much, but I believe it doesn't normally keep a full display buffer.  This might be configurable; hopefully someone can help.  Alternatives for a headless display are to select the null device and output WebGL using rglwidget and view (or print) the results in a browser, or possibly use the new writeASY function to write Asymptote source, and use it to produce the Postscript.

Comment: I should add:  writeASY isn't in 0.95.1441 on CRAN, you'll need to update from R-forge or Github.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. To clarify, I want to automate making PDF output, so an interactive solution via a web browser may not work here.

Comment: Try creating a png file with `rgl.snapshot`. Does that work? Also please post your `sessionInfo` - might be relevant.

Comment: An `rgl.snapshot` call returns a black, empty PNG file of the specified dimensions. I have added a `sessionInfo` transcript to my question. Thanks for any feedback that you might think is useful.

Comment: writeASY may be the best choice.  You'll need to install Asymptote to process the output, but it should all work on a headless display.  Both rgl.postscript and writeASY are incomplete implementations; I'd expect they have different limitations.

Comment: Do you have any proprietary drivers installed that have their own version of libgl? Could you try Xdummy as an alternative to xvfb, and see if that works?

Comment: Perhaps I am not starting it correctly, but Xdummy seems to give the same result as Xvfb.

Comment: Have you tried the same with precompiled package instead of compiling R and rgl from source yourself ??

Comment: No, why would I do that?

Comment: @AlexReynolds I was wondering if you could have missed some dependency or missed compiling some features.

Comment: I don't see an error or other message in the log that suggests that I'm missing a dependency, so I'm not sure. Is there a feature or setting you think is missing, based on the session log or the commands I entered?

Comment: Specifically for `rgl`, can you skip the virtual frame buffer and just try: `library(rgl)` followed by `rgl.useNULL()` ?  Not sure if it will work; just noticed this [recent addition to rgl](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/rgl/docs/rgl.useNULL) from the [docs for shiny](https://www.r-project.org/nosvn/pandoc/shinyRGL.html): _"The ability to use a "null device" was recently added to RGL, allowing you to use RGL (thus shinyRGL) on a headless server without having to emulate a framebuffer using XVFB"_

Comment: rgl.useNULL(TRUE) would work with writeASY() (which writes Asymptote code) or rglwidget() (which writes Javascript), but not with rgl.postscript or rgl.snapshot.

Comment: Since a software solution seems elusive, might an inexpensive hardware solution work for you? Do your headless boxes have any graphics capability? It seems likely, given that most motherboards come with a GPU, even if you don't have a separate graphics card. If they do, you can buy inexpensive dummy video adapters that plug in the hdmi socket, and emulate the existence of a screen. With one of these installed, the box should behave exactly as though it did have a screen.

Answer (score 3):

This seems to be intimately intertwined with the `rgl` package.  Suppose we toss `Xvfb` and friends in favor of `Cairo` and substitute `plot3D` for `rgl`:

```
library(Cairo)
library(plot3D)
CairoPDF()
x <- sort(rnorm(1000))
y <- rnorm(1000)
z <- rnorm(1000) + atan2(x, y)
scatter3D(x, y, z)
dev.off()
```

This still needs to run under X11 (i.e. xterm) but avoids bringing up an X11 window and leaves a PDF plot behind in `Rplots.pdf` (you can control the file names, of course along with lots of the other details of the plot.)

[image]

(Converted to JPEG for insertion here, but it is truly a PDF.)

Comment: I wasn't the one who downvoted you, so I added a vote. This looks interesting but I would need time to investigate that it works without an X11 frame buffer, as well as see if I could recapitulate an existing R/rgl script. Thanks for offering what looks like a potential alternative to rgl.

Comment: @AlexReynolds, after two years and three up votes, have I still not earned the 500 point bounty that was on this question when I put in the time to research and answer it?